# Video playing in background of SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I created a game that has a starting menu screen. In this menu screen, I want a video(I recorded me playing this game via iPhone 6 simulator) to play in the background of this menu screen. I got the video to play, but what happens is when the view loads, it will show the menu, then it will show the video replacing the menu itself.

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit
import AVFoundation




class MenuScene: SKScene {


var player:AVPlayer!
var VideoSprite:SKVideoNode!





override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
let videoURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("startTo32", withExtension: "mov")!

    player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
    player?.actionAtItemEnd = .None
    player?.muted = true


    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.zPosition = -100


    playerLayer.frame = view.frame

    player?.play()


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                     selector: #selector(MenuScene.loopVideo),
                                                     name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
                                                     object: nil)

    view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)


}



func loopVideo() {
    player?.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    player?.play()
}
```

**--------UPDATE--------**

[Here's the link to see what I'm talking about.](https://giphy.com/gifs/QpiOElHce4lSo) the screen with the words is where I'm trying to get the video to play, but instead it just makes the screen go white and then plays the video itself.

Any questions or need for me to add information, just comment.

Thanks, Jordan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using your `SKVideoNode` instead of adding a layer to your view.

Something like this:

```
let videoURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("startTo32", withExtension: "mov")!
VideoSprite = SKVideoNode(url: videoURL)
self.addChild(VideoSprite)
VideoSprite.play()
```

`SKVideoNode` documentation is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKVideoNode/).

Comment: It worked. But how do I resize it. It's too big. Like it's shown zoomed in. I keep trying `VideoSprite.size = CGSize(self.frame)` but I get an error.

Comment: Try `VideoSprite.size = self.frame.size` instead. You are trying to construct a `CGSize` from a `CGRect` (frame) which is why you are getting an error.

Comment: Thanks for both answers. Have a great night(New York).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated video player for Swift 4 and Spritekit:

```
    import SpriteKit
    import UIKit
    import AVFoundation

    class MenuScene: SKScene {

        var player:AVPlayer!
        var VideoSprite:SKVideoNode!

        override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let videoURL: NSURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "yourvideonamehere", withExtension: "mp4")! as NSURL
    VideoSprite = SKVideoNode(url: videoURL as URL)
    self.addChild(VideoSprite)
    VideoSprite.play()

    player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
    player?.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    player?.isMuted = true

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.zPosition = 100

    playerLayer.frame = view.frame

    player?.play()   

}

func loopVideo() {
    player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
    player?.play()
}
}
```

I hope this helps.